# How to execute command after opening new tmux session

Tags: bash, tmux

I'm having some trouble getting a new session to execute a command after creation.

Here's a portion of my **.tmux.conf**:

```
set-window-option -g automatic-rename off
set-option -g allow-rename off
new -A -s 'main' -n 'servers' 'ls' # troubled line
splitw -h -p 35 htop
splitw -v
splitw -v -t 1
splitw -v -t 1
neww -n 'irc' weechat-curses
selectw -t 0
```

This is the line that I'm working on:

```
new -A -s 'main' -n 'servers' 'ls'
```

Here's how I open tmux:

```
alias tux='TERM=screen-256color-bce tmux -f ~/.tmux.conf attach-session -t main'
```

The 'ls' must be causing an error because when it is present, the initial pane doesn't get created. If I change it to 'top', it works fine and the command is executed.

So why does top work and not ls (or any other command I try)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`top` runs until you quit. `ls` exits after it prints the contents of the current directory. This causes the window in which `ls` runs to close.

```
setw -t servers remain-on-exit on
```

should keep the the window named 'servers' from closing after its command exits, but it is complicated by the fact that the window does not exist before the `new-session` command is run, and after `new-session` returns, it may be too late to run the `setw` command (although you can try).

Instead, create a new session in which the default is for a window to remain after its command exists:

```
new -A -s 'main' -n 'servers' 'ls' # troubled line
set -t main set-remain-on-exit on
neww -n 'servers' ls
```

---

Based on your last comment, ignore the above, and replace your `new` command with

```
new -A -s 'main' -n 'servers'
send-keys -t servers.0 ls Enter
```

This creates a regular window, whose command is a regular shell, but then simulates typing the `ls` command at the first shell prompt to provide you with the list of files in that directory. After `ls` completes, you are back in the shell, and the pane will continue to exist until the shell itself completes.

Comment: This doesn't quite work. It creates the initial main session with a window called servers. But when it opens, the pane is dead. I tried tacking on `respawnw -t servers`, but that created a 2nd window called servers with a multiple pane warning.

Comment: See my update. I also have a typo in the original, where the `new` command should simply read `new -A -s 'main'`.

Comment: I had figured out how to use `send-keys` to accomplish what I wanted. It's not as clean as I'd like because you can see the command issued whereas it would be nice to just see the output from the command but it works. Also, I didn't know that you could do the dot notation (`window.pane#`) for the -t flag. That's cool.

Comment: The OP might also consider just using a command like `'ls; bash -l'` or `'ls; while :; do read; done'` with the initial `new-session` (`new`) *tmux* command. Compared to a solution that uses `remain-on-exit`, these both will leave an extra process running, but it may be easier to manage than `remain-on-exit`.